# inserting and removing from a max heap java

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, sorting, heap

I have written my java implementation of a max heap made of nodes that contain two things, a string and a double value that can be accessed from each. They are supposed to be inserted by rank of their double value. I'm not sure if its my insert or remove that isn't working properly, but when I try to remove the top five max values from the heap I'm not getting what I'm supposed to be getting. Any ideas where the hiccup is? There are methods in these such as isfull and isempty to test the base cases of it being empty or full of course... Count is total number of nodes in the array (heap is the array).

```
public boolean insert(String W, double R){

    HeapNode word = new HeapNode(W,R);
    if (isFull()){
        return false;
    }
    else {
        count++;
        heap[count - 1] = word;
        siftUp(count - 1);
    }
    System.out.println("Added");
    return true;
}

public boolean siftUp(int place){

    int parentNode;
    HeapNode tmp;
    if (place != 0) {
        //parent node of place
        //parentNode = getParentNode(place);
        parentNode = ((place-1) / 2);
        if (heap[parentNode].getDouble() < heap[place].getDouble()) {
              tmp = heap[parentNode];
              heap[parentNode] = heap[place];
              heap[place] = tmp;
              siftUp(parentNode);
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Thats the insert, now the remove:

```
public HeapNode remove(){
    HeapNode maxValue;
    if (isEmpty()){
        return null;
    }
    else{
        // Where does the max value always reside? 
        maxValue = heap[0]; 

        // What value will take the root? Last one. 

        heap[0] = heap[count-1]; 
        count--; ;

        // Begin percolate down at index of root 
        int hole = 0; 

        int child; 
        HeapNode temp = heap[hole]; 

        while( hole * 2 + 1 < count) 
        { 
         // Index of left child of node in hole index 
         child = 2 * hole + 1; 

         //find greater child
         if(child != count && (heap[child + 1].getDouble()) > (heap[child].getDouble())) 
            child++; //swap index

         if((heap[child].getDouble()) > (temp.getDouble())) //last comparison
            heap[hole] = heap[child];
         else 
            break; 

         hole = child; 
        } 
        heap[hole] = temp; 
    }
    return maxValue;
}
```

Test case I'm using. Entering nodes in this order based on their double values: 
1.0, 0.8, 0.9, 0.8, 1.0, 0.6, 1.0, 1.0, 0.8, 1.0, 0.7, 1.0, 0.8 
Removing the first five I should be getting all 1.0's? I'm getting 1.0, 0.8, 1.0, 0.7, 1.0 as the five.

Answer (score 1):

I can spot 2 mistakes.

1. You have `parentNode = (place / 2);`
   in the `siftup` method. And apparently you're using 0-based array index so Node 0 is supposed to have 1 and 2 as children, but this equation gives 1 as the parent of 2.
   Change it to `parentNode = ((place-1) / 2);`.
2. The other one is in the next line:
   `if (heap[parentNode].getDouble() > heap[place].getDouble())`.
   This will bubbles the min node to the top, not the max node.

Comment: I still have some errors in the test case I'm using. I am entering the numbers  1.0, 0.8, 0.9, 0.8, 1.0, 0.6, 1.0, 1.0, 0.8, 1.0, 0.7, 1.0, 0.8 in that order and removing the first five I should be getting all 1.0's? I'm getting 1.0, 0.8, 1.0, 0.7, 1.0 as the five.

Answer (score 0):

Another problem you have is this statement in your `remove` method:

```
 //find greater child
     if(child != count && (heap[child + 1].getDouble()) > (heap[child].getDouble())) 
        child++; //swap index
```

Here, you already know that `child < count`, because you tested that in the loop. But if `(child+1) == count`, then you're testing the current element against the previous last element in the heap.

I think what you want is:

```
if ((child < count-1) && (heap[child + 1].getDouble()) > (heap[child].getDouble()))
```